# EPPlus can't read locked cells value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, epplus, epplus-4

I am using EPPlus to read data from .XLSX file.

issue is it is not able to read locked cells. So I have to open excel, Unlock cells, and then upload. Is there way to read lock cells. I tried as below:

```
 For row As Integer = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row + 1 To workSheet.Dimension.[End].Row
            workSheet.Cells(row, vLocation).Style.Locked = False
            Dim strLocation = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells(row, vLocation).Value)

 Next
```

Even i tried following code to unlock the worksheet with EPPlus

```
    Try
        workSheet.Protection.IsProtected = False
        workSheet.Cells("A1:Z200").Style.Locked = False
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

But it does not work. If I unlock cells manually and upload file then it works.

[image]

otherwise following line returns nothing

```
Dim strLocation = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells(row, vLocation).Value)
```

Comment: I assume the sheet has protection turned on (otherwise locking a cell should have no effect).  Is the sheet lock password protected?  Either way it works fine for me.  Maybe post more of your code or post the file somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
 Dim fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {
       Dim ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
       Dim value = ws.Cells[Row, Col].Value;
    }
```